# SSRS - Dataset using different dates (Table)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm creating a report with all of the sales made from each product category. I added a table that contains on the column side: Months and for Rows I have the Product Category (i.e. Chairs, Tables, etc.).

So it should be looking something like this:

```
Product | January | February | March | April
---------------------------------------------
Chairs  | value   | value    | value | value

Tables  | value   | value    | value | value
```

So the thing is that I need to calculate the total amount of chairs sold each month.

I created the query:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity)
FROM Sales
WHERE PurchaseDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
```

That query is inside a Dataset, but I'm looking for a way to use this same Dataset but pass it or change the PurchaseDate range in order to calculate the rest of the sales per month.

Comment: You could try modifying they query to return the results how you want to display them. It looks like you will need to pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Matrix` with the following fields and groups settings:

[image]

In `Row Groups` add Category field and in Column group add a `Parent Group`, use the following expression:

```
=MONTHNAME(MONTH(Fields!PurchaseDate.Value))
```

Use the above expression in the column at the right side of `Category` column.

It will preview the following matrix:

[image]

> Note my example only include dates in January and February, in your
>   case it should show every all months returned by your dataset.

Let me know if this helps.